# Cannot write permissions NTFS partitions

Tags: permissions, partitioning

I have several partitions, mainly, two NTFS for Windows(one for the system, another to share data with Ubuntu), one EXT4 (for "/") and another swap.

I have the next error when trying to save a file using Chrome or Firefox (insuficient permissions).

If I try to create a file with nautilus, it is the same (even when I open Nautilus as root!!).

This is my fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=3b0db9ae-b58b-47d8-ae09-73cc4dca4a39 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /media/c was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=64004A63004A3BF4 /media/c        ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
# /media/d was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=01D19238D33F4D20 /media/d        ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=50f1d3ed-b1e3-49ec-9508-20ccf93921bb none            swap    sw              0       0
```

The problem I have is that I cannot write in both (/media/c nor /media/d partitions) from Ubuntu!! It is very upsetting, because I didn't find anyone with the same kind of problem.

I have a Dual-Boot computer with Windows10 (job purposes) and Ubuntu Gnome 16.10

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you create the mountpoints? /media/c and /media/d ? Are the partitions mounted? Which user IDs belong to the group 46?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your mounts in `/etc/fstab` from:

```
# /media/c was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=64004A63004A3BF4 /media/c        ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
# /media/d was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=01D19238D33F4D20 /media/d        ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
```

to:

```
# /media/c was on /dev/sda2 during installation
#UUID=64004A63004A3BF4 /media/c        ntfs    defaults 0       0
# /media/d was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=01D19238D33F4D20 /media/d        ntfs    defaults 0       0
```

Note: I commented out the mounting of the C: drive because it's not a good idea to modify the C: partition from Ubuntu... Windows doesn't like it.

Then reboot Ubuntu.

If you *must* have the C: drive mounted, you'll need to do this in Windows:

- open the Power control panel
- click on `change what the power buttons do`
- click on `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast start`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve that chkdsk runs at next boot time
- type `chkdsk /f d:` *(if you'd like to check the D: drive)*
- reboot Windows

Comment: Thank you very much! It was perfect and it solved my problem!!

Comment: @zapotec Thanks for the update! Glad you got it going.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used this to solve it:

```bsh
sudo umount /dev/sda2
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2
reboot
```